# How do I adjust logloss for class imbalance in binary classification for machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, math, data-mining, log-likelihood

I'm working on a machine learning project where I need to perform binary classification. I want to minimize the logloss (binary cross entropy loss) of my model. However, the dataset I'm using is split between the two classes 50/50, but the true ratio of the two classes is 96/4. I've been trying to find a formula for 'adjusted logloss' but I'm not sure if it exists or if it's even necessary.

Is there a way to adjust the logloss for class imbalance in binary classification, and if so, what is the formula for it? If not, why is it not needed?

Thanks in advance <3

Tried to find formula for adjusted logloss, but unable to find one. Expected formula, found no solution.

Comment: Do you want to minimize the logloss of the model on data that has a class ratio of 96:4?

Comment: The original ratio of the class=1 in the real distribution is 4/100, but my dataset is balanced 50:50. I already minimised the logloss, but I don't know if I have to search for something like 'adjusted logloss', as it is when you search for accuracy and the classes are artificially balanced so you want to seek for 'adjusted accuracy'.

Comment: I am not sure about what you are trying to achieve. Looks like you are looking for class-weights in log loss function. If so look into - `pos_weight` argument here https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss.html .